# Dynamic url to static url change

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to change my dynamic url to static url for seo please help me.
blow my php code and htaccess code please correct the problem

dynamic url : http://localhost/new/books_list.php?subject_id=2

static url : http://localhost/new/books_list/subject_id/2/

php code:

```
<?php
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

$select=mysql_select_db("test",$connect);

if($_REQUEST[subject_id]!=""){

$subject_id=$_REQUEST[subject_id];
```

htaccess code :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule books_list/subject_id/(.*)/ books_list.php?subject_id=$1
RewriteRule books_list/subject_id/(.*) books_list.php?subject_id=$1
```

help me to solve this problem.
thanks

Comment: That typo is too juicy to fix...

Comment: Please explain exactly what your problem is, errors, etc. and what you have tried to fix it.

Comment: i need to change dynamic url to static only sir

Comment: Sorry, I mean you should edit the question to add more detail, not in a comment to me but in a way that others can better understand. You won't get a good response if you just post code without showing what you tried or where you looked to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
i have a code like this check that and change as per your requirement
# Enable mod_rewrite, start rewrite engine
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
#
# Internally rewrite search engine friendly static URL to dynamic filepath and query
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?product=$1&color=$2&size=$3&texture=$4&maker=$5 [L]
#
# Externally redirect client requests for old dynamic URLs to equivalent new static URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?product=([^&]+)&color=([^&]+)&size=([^&]+)&texture=([^&]+)&maker=([^\ ]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.com/product/%1/%2/%3/%4/%5? [R=301,L]
```